# "Part of the team" vs. "a part of the team"

Tags: indefinite-article, uncountable-nouns, email

I see both of these are used:

> - I'm part of Acme's technical team.
> - I'm **a** part of Acme's technical team.

Which one sounds more natural when introducing myself in an email? Is "Part" countable or uncountable in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a statement by itself,

> I'm **part** of Acme's technical team.

is more natural.

But you could use an article as emphasis or when contrasting with other information.

> He is **a part** of Acme's technical team, even though he does not contribute much.
>
> (after making a big contribution) You see, I *am* **a part** of Acme's technical team.

Answer (score 3):

I would say "I'm part of Acme's technical team."
Another good example is "this online survey is part of my school project"