# "who are a part of" vs "who are part of"

Tags: articles

I saw a comment on instagram that said

> We're extremely worried about thr natural disasters that have been happening in Japan. We as in who are a part of the entertainment industry in Japan."

What's the purpose of having indefinite article "a" before "part" in the second sentence?

Will it be grammatically wrong if it was "...who are part of..."?

I understand the difference of use of indefinite and definite articles but I do not understand when I do not need any articles.

When do you not have to use articles before nouns? (other than uncountable nouns, I know that for words like "water" does not need an article)

Comment: Can you please include the entire sentence? As is, it doesn't really make much sense. Be certain to include punctuation if there is any.

Comment: As the sentence stands it looks decidedly ungrammatical to me. I would expect a "those" before the who, but maybe the whole sentence will clear that up.

Comment: I edited my post. Hope this is easier to understand @Catija

Comment: I edited it. Hope its understandable @DRF

Comment: The second sentence is still gramatically bad. You can't analyze a broken sentence. I think it's missing a comma and a word: "We, as in THOSE who are a part of the entertainment industry in Japan." Which would make it a sentence fragment.

Comment: Related: **[part of the team vs. a part of the team](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48756/part-of-the-team-vs-a-part-of-the-team)**